# Kendo Grid in MVVM and translating or customizing command buttons

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui

This is my MVVM Code and I have troubles customizing the text of Update/Cancel command buttons.
I have customized Edit/Delete buttons but what about the command buttons that are hidden for now and will be visible when I click on Edit button?
Please help me customizing such commands. How can I do that?

```
<div id="grid"  data-role="grid" data-sortable="true" data-editable="inline" data-Scrollable="true"
    data-toolbar='[{name:"create", text:"新しいドメインの追加"}]'
    data-pageable="true"  data-columns='[{field: "Domain", title: "ドメイン", width: 250, filterable: false, sortable: false}, 
                                         {"command": [{name:"destroy",text:"削除"},
                                                      {name:"edit",text:"編集"}]}]' 

    data-bind="source: dataSource, events: { edit: edit, dataBound: dataBound }"></div>
```

Answering this question would help a lot of people who want to customize or translate Update Command or Cancel Command as well as Edit Command or Destroy Command.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle example?

Comment: Sorry I can't work with JSFiddle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to customize the buttons update,cancel,delete,add,edit just do this

```
{
            command : [{
                name : "edit",
                text : {// sets the text of the "Edit", "Update" and "Cancel" buttons
                    edit : "CustomEdit",
                    update : "CustomUpdate",
                    cancel : "CustomCancel"
                },
            }, {
                name : "destroy",
                text : "Destroy"
            } // sets the text of the "Delete" button
            ]
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/delebash/TaTMn/8/)

Answer (score 1):

For localizing `Update` and `Cancel` buttons when you `update` on `popup` mode, you need to define the command as:

```
command: [
    {
        name: "edit",
        text: { edit: "Edita", update: "Actualiza", cancel: "Cancela"}
    },
    {
            name : "destroy",
            text : "Borra"
    }
],
```

**EDIT**: If you also want to change the title of the `popup` window, then you should add `window.title` to `editable` in the grid definition:

```
editable  : {
    mode : "popup",
    window : {
        title: "Edición",
    }
},
```

If you want to take a look into an example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/tTXSJ/)